# Get bounding box for a layer in Mapbox-GL-JS

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using Mapbox-GL-JS and and have a map the users can upload data to S3 and then view it on the map. When a user toggles a layer on I want to use fitBounds to fit the markers into the view.

So the source is added like this:

```
map.addSource(sourceId, {
  type: 'geojson',
  data: 'http://path-to-source,
});
```

Is there any way to do this without calculating the bounding box from the raw geojson when the data is uploaded? I've tried using getLayer and getSource but the bounds are not in there.

Also if there are multiple layers toggled on I wanted to get the bounds for all of the layers together.

Comment: Have you considered using turf.js? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49354133/turf-js-to-find-bounding-box-of-data-loaded-with-mapbox-gl-js

Comment: I can't use turf without downloading the geojson a second time. Some of the geojson may have thousands of points.